# How can I use "frozenColumns" in Google Sheets table?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization

I have a table visualization in Google Sheets. In https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table, there is the `frozenColumns` attribute which does exactly what I want. How can I get this behaviour working in a google sheet table? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found it out by myself. You have to generate the table via script, then you can easily set multiple options including "frozenColumns", e.g.:

```
function createTable() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');

  var chart = sheet.newChart()
  .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.TABLE)
  .addRange(sheet.getRange("A3:L31"))
  .setOption("frozenColumns", 2) //<- Number of columns that should be fixed
  .setOption("sortColumn", 1)    //<- First column is column 0!
  .setNumHeaders(1)
  .setPosition(5, 5, 0, 0)
  .build();

  sheet.insertChart(chart);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to get frozen column you need to specify `frozenColumns` attribute in `table.draw()` section:

```
table.draw(data, {height: '', showRowNumber: true, frozenColumns:1});
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/dlaliberte/Lw5h7c2y/